# Modify an errorbar extent in pandas barplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting data with a pandas barplot that includes errorbars (that are symmetric around the bar top), and I would like to modify the extent of one single errorbar in this plot, so that it shows only on half of it. How can I do that?

Here's a concrete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

bars = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,2), index=['a','b'], columns=['c','d'])
errs = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,2), index=['a','b'], columns=['c','d'])

ax = bars.plot.barh(color=['r','g'],xerr=errs)
```

which yields a plot like that:

[image: barplot example with errorbars]

I'm trying to *a posteriori* access and modify the extent of the errorbar of index `a` and column `d`  so that it shows only the first half of it, i.e. a segment `[bar_top-err, bar_top]` instead of `[bar_top-err, bar_top+err]`. I attempted to retrieve the following matplotlib object:

```
plt.getp(ax.get_children()[1],'paths')[0]
```

which, if I'm not mistaken, is a `Bbox`, and describes the right object, but I can't get to modify it in my plot. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: `type(plt.getp(ax.get_children()[1],'paths')[0])` tells me it is a `matplotlib.path.Path`, actually.

Comment: Sure, it's actually `plt.getp(ax.get_children()[1],'paths')[0].get_extents()` that is of type  `matplotlib.transforms.Bbox`. But concretely, this does not help me figuring out the solution...

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, just need to modify and update the coordinates in `path.vertices`. I took the liberty to assume that you want the error bar to face "away from zero", instead of just showing the negative part of it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

bars = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,2), index=['a','b'], columns=['c','d'])
errs = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,2), index=['a','b'], columns=['c','d'])

ax = bars.plot.barh(color=['r','g'], xerr=errs)
child = ax.get_children()[1]

path = plt.getp(child, 'paths')[0]
bar_top = path.vertices.mean(axis=0)[0]

# replace the right tail if bar is negative or left tail if it's positive
method = np.argmin if np.sign(bar_top)==1 else np.argmax
idx = method(path.vertices, axis=0)[0]
path.vertices[idx, 0] = bar_top

plt.savefig('figs/hack-linecollections.png', dpi=150)
plt.show()
```

[image: hack-linecollections]